# Manually including Webform in a single node

Tags: 7, webforms

Anyone know how to include Webform module into a single node?  Is there a function I can include to do this.

Comment: Do you mean include a webform block in a node?

Comment: Sort of; I want to implement the function directly on a node tpl page.

Answer (score 2):

A [discussion on Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/248157) has resulted in a patch that allows you to display a webform in a block (and then you can display that block only on your node tpl page).

EDIT: The patch has been included in the latest version of webform.

Additionally, you could try using this PHP code:

```
<?php
    $node = node_load($nid);
    print node_view($node);
?>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't need to patch webform - this feature's included with the latest release.

Comment: Oh thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I've edited the answer a bit.